# Lichess' Stockfish's tuning

Tags: stockfish, lichess

I remark that whatever the level of the Lichess' Stockfish I choose it plays in average at the same speed. How could I tune my Stockfish (the one I use in Fritz or Arena) to achieve the same with the same performance ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The settings used for the Stockfish levels on lichess can be found at https://github.com/niklasf/fishnet/blob/53e218bd184554265748513f85d19e601f18c310/fishnet.py#L117-L119:

```
LVL_SKILL = [0, 3, 6, 10, 14, 16, 18, 20]
LVL_MOVETIMES = [50, 100, 150, 200, 300, 400, 500, 1000]
LVL_DEPTHS = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 22]
```

where `LVL_SKILL` refers to the `Skill Level` UCI option in Stockfish, `LVL_MOVETIMES` to the maximum move time in milliseconds, and `LVL_DEPTHS` to the maximum depth for each of the eight levels.

The move time and depth might not be easy to set in a local GUI, but you can simply use the `Skill Level` option to adjust playing strength where 20 means best play and 0 is the lowest available level for Stockfish.